# How to load a jsonl file into BigQuery when the file has mix data fields as columns

Tags: google-bigquery

During my work flow, after extracting the data from API, the JSON has the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "fields": 
    [
      {
        "meta": {
          "app_type": "ios"
        }, 
        "name": "app_id", 
        "value": 100
      }, 
      {
        "meta": {}, 
        "name": "country", 
        "value": "AE"
      }, 
      {
        "meta": {
          "name": "Top"
        }, 
        "name": "position", 
        "value": 1
      }
    ], 
    "metrics": {
      "click": 1, 
      "price": 1, 
      "count": 1
    }
  }
]
```

Then it is store as .jsonl and put on GCS. However, when I load it onto BigQuery for further extraction, the automatic schema inference return the following error:

```
Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: Could not convert value to string. Field: value; Value: 100
```

I want to convert it in to the following structure:

| app_type | app_id | country | position | click | price | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ios | 100 | AE | Top | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Is there a way to define manual schema on BigQuery to achieve this result? Or do I have to preprocess the jsonl file before put it to BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the limitations in [loading JSON data from GCS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json) to BigQuery is that it does not support maps or dictionaries in JSON.
A invalid example would be:

```
"metrics": {
      "click": 1, 
      "price": 1, 
      "count": 1
    }
```

Your jsonl file should be something like this:

```
{"app_type":"ios","app_id":"100","country":"AE","position":"Top","click":"1","price":"1","count":"1"}
```

I already tested it and it works fine.

So wherever you process the conversion of the json files to jsonl files and storage to GCS, you will have to do some preprocessing.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have to options:

- precreate target table with an `app_id` field as an `INTEGER`
- preprocess jsonfile and enclose `100` into quotes like `"100"`